# how to handle BERT "UNK" Token in the output prediction

Tags: json, bert-language-model

I train a pre trained BERT model on my data.
I try to make a Json containing two list:
first: a list conclude prediction of model (desire value)
second: a list of true value

but the first list has many ['UNK'] token in it
some thing like this:
[image]
why this happen? and how can I solve it?

this UNK tag make the prediction result near to zero:(
because the accuracy rate is base on **exact match** of *true* and *desire* and this UNKs make *desire* differ...

what can I do for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ultimately, I found the problem... the Version of Bert I have used was adapted to Persian language and I was not passed the Persian normalizing process completely:)
after completing that phase and some debugging into Bert configuration, it solved:)